# Closing an element when clicked outside the div or its opening button with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two buttons, one of them opens a **form**, and the other one a **dropdown**.

I want both elements to close when clicking outside, the **dropdown is ok** because I want it to close whenever the user clicks outside the opening button.

But the second doesn't work, I want it to close when this logical formula is true:

- (the opening button **'fulfillSetButton' isn't clicked**) **OR** (the
  form **'dateForm' isn't clicked**)

Therefore I've made an event listener for the whole HTML with the formula inside an if statement:

```
html.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(e.target !== (dateForm || fulfillSetButton)){
    dateForm.classList.remove("active");
  }
});
```

But it doesn't work any ideas about what is wrong?

```js
// All the elements
const dropdownButton = document.querySelector("#dropdownToggle"),
      fulfillSetButton = document.querySelector("#fulfillSetButton"),
      dropdownMenu = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu'),
      html = document.querySelector("html"),
      dateForm = document.querySelector(".completion-date");
      

// Preventing default action of submiting the form
function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    e.returnValue = false;
  }
}

// Closing the dropdown *working*
dropdownButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    dropdownMenu.classList.toggle("show");
});

html.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(e.target !== dropdownButton){
    dropdownMenu.classList.remove("show");
  }
});

// Opening the date form
fulfillSetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    dateForm.classList.add("active");
});

// Closing the date form by submiting
dateForm.lastElementChild.addEventListener(
  "click", function () {
    preventDefault();
    dateForm.classList.remove("active");
  }
);

// Closing the date form by clicking outside *not working*
html.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(e.target !== (dateForm || fulfillSetButton)){
    dateForm.classList.remove("active");
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  --trans-left:#84fab0;
  --trans-right:#8fd3f4;
  --background: #fff;
  --color: #222;
}

.button-list {

  align-self: center;
}

.completion-date {

  display: block;
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    top: -100%;
    left: calc(50% - 121px);
    min-width: max-content;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    background: var(--background);
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 18px -6px var(--color);
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.completion-date.active {

  top: calc(50% - 264px);
}

.completion-date div {

    margin: 0.5rem;
}

.completion-date input,
.completion-date button {

    margin: auto 0;
}

.completion-date input {

  width: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.completion-date div > button {

  width: 1.5rem;
  margin: auto 3px;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

section {

  width: 100vw;
}

input {

  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 7px -3px black;
  border: none;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

button {

  padding: 9px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 9px -10px var(--color), inset 0 0 15px -12px var(--color);
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.entry {

  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 30vh;

  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, var(--trans-left) 0%, var(--trans-right) 100%);
}

@media screen and (max-height: 660px) {

    .entry {

      height: 38vh;
    }
}

form {

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  max-width: 36rem;

  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

form > * {

  max-height: 100%;
}

form > div {

  display: flex;
}

form > input {

  margin: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 9px -4px #000000;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.second-item {

  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.second-item > * {

  margin: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px -6px #000000, -4px -4px 10px -3px #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.dropdown-wrap > *:first-child {
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px -6px #000000, -4px -4px 10px -3px #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 6px;
}


.dropdown-wrap > *:first-child {
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px -6px #000000, -4px -4px 10px -3px #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 6px;
}

.btn.dropdown {

  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.btn.dropdown.low {

  background-color: #84fab0;
}

.btn.dropdown.high {

  background-color: #ffa0a0;
}

.dropdown-menu {

  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;

  margin-top: 9px;

  list-style: none;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;

  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px -9px black;
  border-radius: 9px;

  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;

  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.dropdown-menu > li {

  padding: 0.4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu.show {

  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="entry">
        <form autocomplete="off">
          <input type="text" id="taskText">
          <div class="second-item">
            <button type="button" id="fulfillSetButton">Date form</button>
            <div class="dropdown-wrap">
              <button class="btn dropdown" type="button" id="dropdownToggle">Dropdown button</button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="taskPriority" style="background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(132,250,176,1) 0%, rgba(132,250,176,1) 33%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 33%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 66%, rgba(255,160,160,1) 66%, rgba(255,160,160,1) 100%); color: #000">
                <li>Vysoká</li>
                <li>Střední</li>
                <li>Nízká</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <form class="completion-date">
        <h2>Dokončit za:</h2>
        <div>
          <button onclick="increaseValue(months)">+</button>
          <input id="months" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="12">
          <button onclick="decreaseValue(months)">-</button>
          <p>měsíců</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onclick="increaseValue(weeks)">+</button>
          <input id="weeks" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="5">
          <button onclick="decreaseValue(weeks)">-</button>
          <p>týdnů</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onclick="increaseValue(days)">+</button>
          <input id="days" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="31">
          <button onclick="decreaseValue(days)">-</button>
          <p>dní</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onclick="increaseValue(hours)">+</button>
          <input id="hours" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="23">
          <button onclick="decreaseValue(hours)">-</button>
          <p>hodin</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onclick="increaseValue(minutes)">+</button>
          <input id="minutes" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="59">
          <button onclick="decreaseValue(minutes)">-</button>
          <p>minut</p>
        </div>
        <button>Nastavit</button>
      </form>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(e){
if( div.contains(e.target)){
    //click inside of element  
} else{
    //click outside of element
  }
});
```

I fixed some CSS and HTML to.

```js
// All the elements
const dropdownButton = document.querySelector("#dropdownToggle"),
      fulfillSetButton = document.querySelector("#fulfillSetButton"),
      dropdownMenu = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu'),
      html = document.querySelector("body"),
      dateForm = document.querySelector("#completion-date-id");
      

// Preventing default action of submiting the form
function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    e.returnValue = false;
  }
}

// Closing the dropdown *working*
dropdownButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    dropdownMenu.classList.toggle("show");
});
//new way works every spot on page
window.addEventListener('click', function(e){
if( dropdownButton.contains(e.target)){
  } else{
    dropdownMenu.classList.remove("show");
  }
});
//Old way
//html.addEventListener("click", function(e){
//  if(e.target !== dropdownButton){
//    dropdownMenu.classList.remove("show");
//  }
//});

// Opening the date form
fulfillSetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    dateForm.classList.add("active");
});

// Closing the date form by submiting
dateForm.lastElementChild.addEventListener(
  "click", function () {
    preventDefault();
    dateForm.classList.remove("active");
  }
);

// Closing the date form by clicking outside *working now*
window.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    
if( dateForm.contains(e.target) || fulfillSetButton.contains(e.target)){
  } else{
    dateForm.classList.remove("active");
  }
});
// Closing the date form by clicking outside *not working*
//html.addEventListener("click", function(e){
//  if(e.target !== (dateForm || fulfillSetButton)){
//    dateForm.classList.remove("active");
//  }
//});
```

```css
:root {
  --trans-left:#84fab0;
  --trans-right:#8fd3f4;
  --background: #fff;
  --color: #222;
}

.button-list {

  align-self: center;
}

.completion-date {
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    top: -100%;
    left: calc(50% - 121px);
    min-width: max-content;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    background: var(--background);
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 18px -6px var(--color);
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.completion-date.active {

  top: calc(50% - 264px);
}

.completion-date div {

    margin: 0.5rem;
}

.completion-date input,
.completion-date button {

    margin: auto 0;
}

.completion-date input {

  width: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.completion-date div > button {

  width: 1.5rem;
  margin: auto 3px;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

section {

  width: 100vw;
}

input {

  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 7px -3px black;
  border: none;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

button {

  padding: 9px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 9px -10px var(--color), inset 0 0 15px -12px var(--color);
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.entry {

  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 30vh;

  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, var(--trans-left) 0%, var(--trans-right) 100%);
}

@media screen and (max-height: 660px) {

    .entry {

      height: 38vh;
    }
}

form {

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  max-width: 36rem;

  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

form > * {

  max-height: 100%;
}

form > div {

  display: flex;
}

form > input {

  margin: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 9px -4px #000000;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.second-item {

  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.second-item > * {

  margin: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px -6px #000000, -4px -4px 10px -3px #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.dropdown-wrap > *:first-child {
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px -6px #000000, -4px -4px 10px -3px #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 6px;
}


.dropdown-wrap > *:first-child {
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px -6px #000000, -4px -4px 10px -3px #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 6px;
}

.btn.dropdown {

  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.btn.dropdown.low {

  background-color: #84fab0;
}

.btn.dropdown.high {

  background-color: #ffa0a0;
}

.dropdown-menu {

  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;

  margin-top: 9px;

  list-style: none;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;

  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px -9px black;
  border-radius: 9px;

  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;

  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.dropdown-menu > li {

  padding: 0.4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu.show {

  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
}
.active{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
<section class="entry">
        <form autocomplete="off">
          <input type="text" id="taskText">
          <div class="second-item">
            <button type="button" id="fulfillSetButton">Date form</button>
            <div class="dropdown-wrap">
              <button class="btn dropdown" type="button" id="dropdownToggle">Dropdown button</button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="taskPriority" style="background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(132,250,176,1) 0%, rgba(132,250,176,1) 33%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 33%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 66%, rgba(255,160,160,1) 66%, rgba(255,160,160,1) 100%); color: #000">
                <li>Vysoká</li>
                <li>Střední</li>
                <li>Nízká</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <form id="completion-date-id" class="completion-date active">
        <h2>Dokončit za:</h2>
        <div>
          <button onclick="increaseValue(months)">+</button>
          <input id="months" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="12">
          <button onclick="decreaseValue(months)">-</button>
          <p>měsíců</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onclick="increaseValue(weeks)">+</button>
          <input id="weeks" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="5">
          <button onclick="decreaseValue(weeks)">-</button>
          <p>týdnů</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onclick="increaseValue(days)">+</button>
          <input id="days" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="31">
          <button onclick="decreaseValue(days)">-</button>
          <p>dní</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onclick="increaseValue(hours)">+</button>
          <input id="hours" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="23">
          <button onclick="decreaseValue(hours)">-</button>
          <p>hodin</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onclick="increaseValue(minutes)">+</button>
          <input id="minutes" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="59">
          <button onclick="decreaseValue(minutes)">-</button>
          <p>minut</p>
        </div>
        <button>Nastavit</button>
      </form>
      </section>
</body>
```

Comment: I also fixed some JavaScript in some parts.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: It did, thank you, but can you explain in the answer why did this function worked but my didn't?
It would really help me understand it more, I can't find it elsewhere.

Comment: It was because the html tag that you had selected was not on the same level as the popup element using the window option is the best way to do it as far as I know. Please mark this as the correct answer if it solved your problem. :)